# Notification of a php web site to a web application laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am currently working on a project which I have to set up a web application management with `laravel 5.4`, so my problem is that there is already the website with `php5` in which there is an application form I want That once someone adds an application I get a notification in my web application with laravel I worked this way, the notification is inserted in the database but does not show up in my space.

**my code php**

```
$requser = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE role = 1");
$requser->execute();
$user = $requser->fetch();
$typen="App\Notifications\Candnotif";
$notif_type="App\User";
foreach ($user as $u) {
  $sql1 = 'INSERT  into notifications (id,type,notifiable_id,notifiable_type) VALUES(" 7","'.$typen.'","'.$user['id'].'","'.$notif_type.'")';
  $bdd->exec($sql1);
}
```

Comment: how are you showing the notifications?

Comment: <span class="badge bg-important">{{Auth::user()->notifications->count()}}</span>

Comment: Share your User model code.

Comment: <?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
     public function demandes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Demande','id_user');
    }
        public function creche(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Creche','id_creche');
    }
    public function absencecollabs(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Absencecollab','id_user');
    }
      public function bulletins(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Bulletin','id_user');
    }
}